# Is it possible to change the column type of a column while the list already is created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column

Is it possible to change the column type of a SharePoint column while the SharePoint List is already created?

Comment: From which column type to which column type you want to change? Are there existing list items (data) in list?

Comment: I need to change the columntype from Text to Choice. Can this be done with data in the list and can this be done without data in the list?

Comment: Yes, you can change from text to choice. But, you have to manually enter the choices/options in column settings.

Comment: I want to close this question. But how?

Comment: I have added our discussion as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can change the column from single line text to choice.

But, you have to manually enter the choices/options in column settings:

[image]